# How can I slice a dataframe at different column numbers for each row?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a numpy array like this:

```
x = np.array([[False, False,  True],
              [False,  True,  True],
              [ True,  True, False],
              [ True,  True, False],
              [False, False,  True],
              [False,  True,  True],
              [ True,  True, False],
              [ True,  True, False]])
```

and some index locations like this:

```
idx = (np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), np.array([2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
```

I can index slice `x` like so:

```
x[idx]
output:
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

However if I have a dataframe like so:

```
                         0      1      2
2020-01-01 01:10:00  False  False   True
2020-01-01 01:15:00  False   True   True
2020-01-01 01:20:00   True   True  False
2020-01-01 01:25:00   True   True  False
2020-01-02 01:10:00  False  False   True
2020-01-02 01:15:00  False   True   True
2020-01-02 01:20:00   True   True  False
2020-01-02 01:25:00   True   True  False
```

I cant index slice this dataframe in the same way:

```
df.iloc[idx]

output:
                         2      1      0      0      2      1      0      0
2020-01-01 01:10:00   True  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
2020-01-01 01:15:00   True   True  False  False   True   True  False  False
2020-01-01 01:20:00  False   True   True   True  False   True   True   True
2020-01-01 01:25:00  False   True   True   True  False   True   True   True
2020-01-02 01:10:00   True  False  False  False   True  False  False  False
2020-01-02 01:15:00   True   True  False  False   True   True  False  False
2020-01-02 01:20:00  False   True   True   True  False   True   True   True
2020-01-02 01:25:00  False   True   True   True  False   True   True   True
```

I could use loops to do this, but what is the fastest way to slice a data frame at different column positions, for each row?

If I have to use loops, it may end up being faster to create a NumPy array, then slice the array and convert it back to a data frame at the end.

Comment: `df.values[idx]`?

Comment: @Corralien that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.values` from your dataframe:

```
>>> df.values[idx]
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this as the answer when it allows me to!